# What is the largest number of runs scored with one out remaining in an MLB game?

Tags: baseball, trivia, mlb

In major league baseball, what is the largest number of runs scored by a team with only one out remaining in the bottom of the last inning? I could find records only for the largest number of runs scored in the bottom of the ninth.

Comment: [Possibly 10 runs](http://www.sportsecyclopedia.com/al/wasdc/nats.html). `On May 23rd [1901] when the Senators had a nine run lead in the ninth inning with two outs and nobody on base for the Cleveland Blues. However, the Blues stage an amazing comeback and take the game 14-13.`

Comment: Although not a direct answer to your question - an interesting read:  https://www.fangraphs.com/tht/tht-live/10-year-anniversary-of-baseballs-greatest-comeback/